# Laravel 4 deployment required files

Tags: php, deployment, laravel, laravel-4

I want to publish my Laravel 4 App to my server, but I have two questions I would like to ask first:

- What do I have to publish? As I don't want to have things in the server like composer, etc…
- Is there any "simple way" to publish it to my server, like `php artisan publish` or something like that, that only published the updated files to the server!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way as in terms of configuration and without composer is to transfer all the files in your project (including the vendors directory) to the server via `FTP`.

Notes:

(1) Using different configuration files for local deployment and production server will make your job even much easier. Laravel will detect the environment and apply the corresponding database configuration and everything else that you will define there.

(2) As an additional idea, you might consider deploying a private git repository onto the server, and then define it as a remote called `production`. After doing so, you will be able to just push the changes with a single command: `git push production`. This will set you free from remembering which files to transfer in order to apply the latest changes onto the production server.

Comment: Thanks. Any direction on a good starting point for a completely git noob?

Answer (score 0):

First time you have to copy the entire files to your online server. After that, you can copy the updated files from your `app` or `assets` folder.